# Весы КСО NCR какой протокол используется

Tags: usb, драйвер, sdk, protocol, scale

Имеется весовая платформа безопасности от кассы самообслуживания NCR, никакого SDK к нему нет(или я не нашёл). Хотелось бы понять, что за протокол используется для получения веса.

О весовой платформе:
Подключается по USB. Отображается как HID.
Manufacturer: NCR Corp.
Product: K118 NCR FL5 20011004@1442

Перехваченные данные передаваемые через usb выглядят так:
0x0A(символ "\n") всегда имеется в начале пакета.
0x0D(символ "\r") всегда имеется в конце пакета.
пакеты - это строки с завершающим нулём.

При запросе веса на устройство передаётся следующая строка: "\nS 25\r",
в hex viewer'е это выглядит так:

```
00000000: 0A 53 20 32 35 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .S 25...........
```

На что весы отвечают: "\n25(SQ00000000)=0037C99A 0\r"

```
00000000: 0A 32 35 28 53 51 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 29 3D  .25(SQ00000000)=
00000010: 30 30 33 37 43 39 39 41 20 30 0D 00 00 00 00 00  0037C99A 0......
```

0037C99A - это вес

Может кто видел подобный протокол или что-то похожее?

Comment: 0037C99A очень похоже на 32х битный оффсет, в памяти.

Зачастую производители немного читерствуют в данном случае... Надо посмотреть следующую команду от мастера к слейву где используется 0037C99A ... То-есть есть IO доступная память + текстовый протокол...  0A - это ошибка твоей программки, она считывает только 1 байт а надо 2  "\r\n"  53 20 это команда запроса, в ответ на которую он даёт ответ что реальное значение находиться по адресу 0037C99A   далее \0 сишный конец строки, \r\n следующая команда.

Comment: А вот такая документация не подойдет?  https://onlinehelp.ncr.com/Retail/Scanners/Legacy/7884/1819.pdf

Не факт что NCR Corp от версии к версии протокол меняет.

Comment: 0a(\n) в начале и 0d(\r) в конце - видимо просто такой протокол.  
  
0037C99A - вес в попугаях. Если взять этот вес за ноль, потом положить 1кг и сохранить это значение. То потом можно на основе этого вычислять текущий вес.  
  
53 20 - это ascii символы: S и пробел  
  
Это я уже понял и с этим уже можно работать. Просто не хочется изобретать велосипед. Может кто узнает этот протокол, мало ли.  
  
Я уже много "User Guide"ов просмотрел, там нет ничего.  
Но всё-равно спасибо

Comment: Врядле есть готовые решения, а если и есть то они остаются в недрах разработчиков. Могу пожелать только удачного разбора сей штуки. За 10 лет Hardware программирования, некогда не было легко, обязательно приходит новое устройство и методом научного тыка и долбёжки производителя устройства становиться ясно что с этим устройством делать. А ещё на такие вопросы периодический на https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ можно найти ответ. Там такие-же Hardware'шики сидят наряду с ардуинщиками.